# How do I add information from a data frame onto a US Map in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame based on the global terrorism database called `gtd` in R.

I have the maps package downloaded/required

What I am trying to do is take data from my `gtd` data frame and add the points on a US map.

I know the code for the USA map is `map("state")`

in my `gtd` data frame, there is a column for latitude and longitude

all I want to do is plot the points on the US map to show location of where terrorist attacks happened in US

so from my gtd database to only get a subset where American longitude/latitude is needed I know I would use

```
subset(x=gtd, country_txt=="United States")
```

but from there, how to I plot the location of attacks as points on the USA map?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make the broad assumption from clues in your post that you're using data from the  [global terrorism database](http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/contact/). If you've managed to read in the huge CSV from it, what you want to do should work and you're really close to having the answer. Basically, you just need to add the `points()` to the `map()`:

```
library(maps)

# assuming you have it in a CSV file
dat <- read.csv("gtd.csv")

# subset only points in the US
US <- dat[dat$country_txt == "United States",]

# plot the base US map
map('state')

# add points with really horrid default color, point type & size
# changing this is a good exercise for the poster :-)
points(x=US$longitude, y=US$latitude, col="red", cex=0.75)
```

[image: map]

This has nothing to do with `ggplot2` though, so consider removing that tag. It can be done with `ggplot` but `maps()` doesn't use it.

Comment: thank you very much, yes I had the cdv imported. As you and everyone else can see, I am very new to R/ the world of programming/ this website.

Comment: you got pretty far and just needed a bit more of a nudge. definitely take the time to play with the various map and plot settings. you can create some really compelling cartographic visualizations with R.

Comment: I have to be missing an element- with that exact code I can get the map to plot, but when I try to add the lat/long points I get the error "Error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x, y), type = type, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet"

Comment: You may want to restart your R or RStudio session. It sounds like the graphics device may be a bit wonky. Also, you might want to add output of a `dput(head(IS))` (or `gtd` instead of `US`) to your post to ensure it's similar to what I've assumed it to be.

Comment: ha, all it ended up being is that I closed out of the USA map that popped up in quartz after running map('states').. works perfectly now thank you so much!

Comment: glad it helps. definitely play with the point sizes. (and don't forget to accept the answer :-)